# Does every set of Lebesgue measure greater than zero have an accumulation point?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a set with $\lambda^n(A)>0$ where $\lambda^n$ is the Lebesgue measure can we conclude that $A$ has an accumulation point?

Comment: It cannot be countable, since countable sets have measure zero. Now, uncountable sets have accumulation points. To see this tessellate the space with cubes of side $1$. Since there are countably many cubes at least one of them contains uncountably many elements of the set. Now start dividing that cube in cubes of half the side and picking a sub-cube that contains infinitely many elements of the set. Divide each new selected cube and again choose one with infinitely many elements of the set. The sequence of cubes selected intersect at an accumulation point of the set.

Comment: Yes, because $A$ is uncountable and therefore has an accumulation point by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: @DavidKraemer Bolzano-Weierstrass is about sequential compactness. I don't see how it applies here.

Comment: @Math1000 It requires doing the first step in the first comment, but it applies.

Comment: @conditionalMethod A cube that contains uncountably many elements of $A$ is closed and bounded, so there exists some sequence in that cube which has a convergent subsequence, whose limit is an accumulation point of $A$. Correct?